Abel summation on smooth piecewise function
After reading this article on non-analytic smooth functions, I wondered if is possible to apply the Abel Summation Formula to such a function. The respective Wikipedia articles assert that Abel Summation is valid for continuously differentiable functions, and that a function such as
$$
f(x) :=
\begin{cases} 
\exp(-1/x),  & \mbox{if }x>0 \\
0, & \mbox{if }x\le0
\end{cases}
$$
is indeed continuously differentiable, though not analytic. But, this being Wikipedia, I thought it wise to check!
MODIFIED FROM HERE TO ACCOUNT FOR COMMENTS BELOW
So, purely by way of example, say I wanted to apply Abel Summation to the sum $\sum_{k=1}^x f(a k-b)$. Set $\phi (k) = f(a k - b)$. Then Abel Summation gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^x f(a k-b)
&= \sum _{k=1}^x \phi (k) \\
&= \lfloor x\rfloor \phi (x) -\int_1^x \lfloor u\rfloor  \frac {\delta}{\delta u} \phi (u) \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \lfloor x\rfloor f \left(a x - b \right) -\int_1^x \lfloor u\rfloor  \frac {\delta}{\delta u} f \left(a u - b \right) \mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$
Set $a = 2$, $b = 5$ (random choices, but this is only an example). Calculating numerical results in Mathematica suggests that this is correct (it won't directly integrate an expression involving the floor function, so one must use NIntegrate):

However, the fact that it works does not make it mathematically acceptable. I could theoretically use this in a proof and get shot down in flames because one cannot apply Abel Summation to a piecewise continuous function. It might not be sufficiently rigorous.
And that is my question: is it (generally and rigorously) valid to apply Abel Summation to this kind of piecewise continuous function?

What have you tried?

I’m just asking if it’s possible from a technical point of view. i.e., if I went ahead and did it, would the result be technically valid? Even if it produced the right result, it might not turn out to be probably right. So, that’s just an example; I am asking about Abel Summation on this kind of piecewise smooth function in general.

I mean, have you tried to prove that it works for that kind of functions?

I'm asking if a worked example would be technically valid, even if it works. It's possible for something to work, but not be strictly proven or supported...

You're in a Mathematics forum. In Mathematics, if one says something works, even an example, one needs to prove its claim.

But my question is a completely general one about smooth functions and Abel Summation, hence the word “say”. I’ll test it out and add that detail - but then we’ll end discussing a specific function, which isn’t my aim at all.

Hi @jjagmath, I hope the above changes make things clear. The question is not about a specific choice of $f$ and working through an example, it is about the generality of the approach. It works, but is it sufficiently rigorous to be acceptable as part of a proof?

I was suggesting you to try to prove that the formula (it's pretty straightforward), but I see that you have put effort on the question. Yes, the Wikipedia is right, you only need the function to be continuously differentiable.

Thank you @jjagmath  :-)
